# AngularJS have an image updated that has the same path

Tags: image, angularjs, refresh

My Python server sends an update to my AngularJS to update an image.
However, the image has the same location on server : Only the content of the image change.

My image is not updated.

Here is my code:

```
<img src="{{imgSrc}}"></img>

$scope.$on 'askInfo', (sender, image) ->    
$scope.imgSrc = angular.copy(image)
```

When the event is received, the server has updated the image. However, the location of the image is still the same, so only the first picture is displayed.

I have found an ugly workaround :
imgSrc = /File/img.jpg?000000x
where x increments each time...

Seems to work so far, but is it reliable ?

Comment: Even if you are able to get the watchers to fire, I suspect that the browser will not fetch the image unless you change the URL. Also, addition of query strings is fairly common backward-compatible (read: IE) practise which will work.